# moving vertices in quad view

Tags: vertices

I am in top view and moved my vertices to where i want them. I go to right view and all the vertices move out of position in top view. Is there a way to stop top view moving while moving in right view.

Thanks in

Comment: Could you better explain your problem? All the windows are showing the same geometry, only the point of view changes. If you move one vertex from 0,0,0 to 0,0,1 this change will be shown in all the viewport. From what I was able to understand, you would like to work in each view indipendently from the other. Am I right? May I ask what's the purpose of this?

Comment: Hi Carlos
I am trying to model airplane. In top view i have vertices match exactly to top of windscreen. In right view i try to move vertices to match top of windscreen, and in top view the vertices move so they dont match anymore.

Comment: In top view you should adjust only the X and Y coordinates of every vertex. In the right view you should adjust only the Z coordinate (press G an then Z to restrict grabbing axis), so in the top view you'll see no movements.